# laravel Javascript and Render sections

Tags: javascript, laravel, rendering

Hi I did a webapp with laravel, with various forms that add datas to database and then refresh only some sections (for example insert an order, then insert some products...etc), but when section render javascript doesn't work anymore.
I have some Jquery that catch some events...for example some click buttons.
EXAMPLE

PART of script in the HEAD

```
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/vendor/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/vendor/holder.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).ajaxSend(function() {
            $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);　
            });

            $('#searchPolizza').keydown(function (e) {
              if (e.keyCode == 13) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $value=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'get',
                    url : "{{ url("/trova") }}",
                    data:{'numero':$value},
                    success:function(data){
                    $('#RefreshContent').replaceWith(data);
                    //initRefundsFunctions();
                    //initDossierListClick();
                    }
                });
              }
            });

$( "#addDossier" ).click(function( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();

          //$("#addDossierForm")[0].reset();
          var r = confirm("Vuoi veramente creare un nuovo dossier?");
            if (r == true) {
                       ....continue.......</script>
```

After i found a "polizza" calling ajax '#searchPolizza' Then i refresh content section

Part of RefreshContent section where i have a form with button #addDossier that i can press after refresh section related to first search

```
<div class="" style="zoom:90%">
  <form class="form-inline" id="addDossierForm"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="dossier" id="dossier">
    <input type="date" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" placeholder="data sinitro" id="date_cla">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-customer_id="@isset($customer_id){{$customer_id}}@endisset" id="addDossier"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

But jquery cannot catch anymore the click event

I tried to put all script in the head or also to create function to recall but it doesn't work well.
Is there another solution?
Thx

Comment: Are you using ajax requests to update the sections? Maybe you are changing the DOM in a way that script can't trace it. You should use something like VueJs, which updates the DOM dynamically.

Comment: I inserted part of my code....yes i use ajax....

Answer (score 0):

Here, `$(dom).click()` binds events statically, You should try registering you click event function like this:

`$( '#addDossier' ).on( 'click', function (event) { your code});`

which binds event handler dynamically, [check that out here](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and you could use shorthand `(function(){..})();` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){...});` and you should consider using something modern like Vue/React. Jquery is primitive and getting older.